# session won't start when running "isset" through a function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm creating a valid credential function for a log in page.
The function works if I use it outside the function using the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array(":email" => $email));
    $results = $query->fetchAll();

    if($results !=FALSE && $query->rowCount() > 0) {
    if($results[0]['password'] == $password){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
}
```

But if I call the function from the external function, nothing happens as if there was something wrong with the log in credentials.

**the function:**

```
 function valid_credientials($email,$password){
    global $db;

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array(":email" => $email));
    $results = $query->fetchAll();
    if($results !=FALSE && $query->rowCount() > 0) {
    if($results[0]['password'] == $password){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

}}

}
```

and the `isset` post:

```
 if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])){
        if (valid_credientials($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']) == false ){
        $errors[] = 'No matching email found.';
    }
        if (empty($errors)){
            $_SESSION['email'] = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

            header("Location: profile.php");
                die();

        }
    }
```

I was thinking about trouble with the connection, but if I use this function it returns the emails.

```
function valid_credientials($email,$password){
    $test = $db->query("SELECT `email` FROM `user`");
    while($row = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        echo $row['email'], '<br>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is not "session" but the very code you wrote. As it's your own code, your problem is just lack of debugging. As it's lack of debugging, this question doesn't fit for Q&A site, being too localized. Even if volunteers will debug your code for you, it won't help any further visitor.

Comment: agree with `your common sense`, but just to help, you're not returning anything in your function. Write some explicit true/false return values to make sure your function can pass the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code,

```
function valid_credientials($email,$password){
    global $db;

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array(":email" => $email));
    $results = $query->fetchAll();
    if($results !=FALSE && $query->rowCount() > 0) {
    if($results[0]['password'] == $password){
       $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    }
}
```

You are getting values from $_POST, you don't need these two line at all as you have email and password in your function parameters.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

And also you check for return value of the function  but there is nothing returned by your function. go through the code below, it returns true or false depending on the condition.

```
function valid_credientials($email,$password){
    global $db;

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array(":email" => $email));
    $results = $query->fetchAll();
    if($results !=FALSE && $query->rowCount() > 0) {
    if($results[0]['password'] == $password){
       $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to return the value with something like this. 
started with POD this morning so quite new :)
$valid = $query->fetchColumn();
if($valid){
$success = true;
}
return $succes;

Comment: I recommend you go through doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to know about what it returns and how to compare. Even I'm new to PDO as well. I answered because you had  general problem. As I'm aware the `fetchAll()` returns false if there are no more rows or else returns single column from next result set. So yoou are comparing $valid with nothing and you are checkong for true value. Please check and get it corrected with the proper comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Your `valid_credentials` function doesn't return a value.

The below if statement, will return NULL ( not positive on this, just guessing ), which isn't equal to false, so the errors array is still empty during the next if statement

```
if (valid_credientials($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']) == false ){
    $errors[] = 'No matching email found.';
}
if (empty($errors)){

}
```